# Pig_Latin Translator & for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pig Latin translator is basically an introductory code for many projects, and it involves getting words that start with consonants to move the first letter to the end of the word and add 'ay', and adding only 'ay' to a word that starts with a vowel. I have basically finished the whole project except for some places, and one main thing is getting the program to complete a whole sentence with a for loop, especially in moving to the next list item

I have tried to do simple things such as n+1 at the end of the for loop, and researched online (majority on Stackoverflow)

```
latin = ""
n = 0

sentence = input ("Insert your sentence ")
word = sentence.split()
first_word = word [n]
first_letter = first_word [0]
rest = first_word [1:]
consonant = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z')
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for one in consonant :
    latin = latin + " " + rest + one + "ay"
    print (latin)
    n + 1
for one in vowel :
    latin = latin + " " + first_word +ay
    print (latin)
    n + 1
```

There was no error message, however, the computer ran the variable 'one' not as the first (zeroth) letter of the variable first_word, rather, just running it from a - z. Is there anyway to fix this? Thank you

Comment: Does your code run? It doesn't run when I copy and paste it.

Comment: It does, but the result is really weird

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

sentence = input("Insert your sentence ")

# don't forget "y" :)
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# this empty list will hold our output
output_words = list()

# we'll take the user's input, strip any trailing / leading white space (eg.: new lines), and split it into words, using spaces as separators.
for word in sentence.strip().split():
    first_letter = word[0]
    # check if the first letter (converted to lower case) is in the consonants list
    if first_letter.lower() in consonants:
        # if yes, take the rest of the word, add the lower case first_letter, then add "ay"
        pig_word = word[1:] + first_letter.lower() + "ay"
    # if it's not a consonant, do nothing :(
    else:
        pig_word = word
    # add our word to the output list
    output_words.append(pig_word)

# print the list of output words, joining them together with a space
print(" ".join(output_words))
```

The loop loops over each word in the sentence - no need to count anything with `n`. There's also no need to loop over the consonants or the vowels, all we care about is "does this word start with a consonant" - if yes, modify it as per your rules.

We store our (possibly) modified words in an output list, and when we're done, we print all of them, joined by a space.

Note that this code is very buggy - what happens if your user's input contains punctuation?

`I opehay hattay elpshay, eyuleochoujay`

Comment: Hi Danielle, Thank you for the answer, I want to ask some questions regarding the functions and clarify somethings. So, what is the functions of .append from line 28, and the .join function at the end of the code.

Comment: @JeyuLeoChou `append()` is a list methods - `output_words` starts off as an empty list. Then we `.append()` each word to the list, whether we translated it to pig latin or not. Once we're done, we `.join()` each of those words into a string, using the `" "` empty space as a separator between each one - and `print()` that string.